# Setup Featured image on all posts from thesis thesis_post_image custom field?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, featured-post

I moved from thesis to other wp theme and i want to change the thesis post images (these are saved under thesis_post_image in database )as featured images. Site have over 1000+ posts.

Is there a way to run a code to change the thesis_post_image urls in the database to the featured image field in the database?

Comment: Can you post an example `thesis_post_image` value?